# ClickOnce for a windows application

Tags: asp.net, clickonce

I have an image viewer plugin called SuperViewer (it is a windows control). I would like to use it as contol in my web page. I could succeeded to use. Now, I want to:

Publish the 'SuperViewer' using Visual Studio 2008, to use with the [ClickOnce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ClickOnce) technique. If my web page loads, I have to check whether the plug in is installed or not. If it is installed, nothing to do. Otherwise, I need to show a button called 'Launch SuperViewer Installer' and install the published set up using ClickOnce technology.

[image]

I succeeded to study ClickOnce from MSDN. How do I do the other stuff?

Comment: then why do you have firefox screenshot?

Comment: Is your application a browser plugin or are you wanting your browser to detect if your application has been installed?

Comment: @RLH :- The browser should detect if my application is installed or not

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the forum post *[ClickOnce for windows application](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winformssetup/thread/14aad8bf-1468-4023-afa8-768fa14ffc5e)*.